# Estimating summary statistics for a distribution from a sample and some sample statistics

Tags: self-study, distributions, fitting

**Here is the question that I am trying to solve.**
Given:

- One in eight items in a production process was sampled.
- This resulted in 11,341 samples from the process
- These were tested for the presence of a biological pathogen
- After growing culture from these test about 817 had more than 2 colonies
- The mean number of colonies in those 817 was between 7 and 11
- There were 50 samples that had between 10 to 15 colonies.  These comprise the sampled right tail of the data.
- (note: there may be growth over time, so higher colony counts relate to higher initial populations.

Assuming:

- The sample represents the population
- The samples were drawn i.i.d. and treated identically

Find:

- a reasonable approximation of what the distribution of colonies would
  look like if it were taken across the entire population.
- an estimate for the 50th, 90th, and 99th percentiles of colonies if the whole population were tested.

**Here how I am trying to engage it.**

Approaches:

- Write down the things that we know (number of elements with mean or max colony counts within window) and use a computer program totry to find best fits for a number of distributions, and think about the ones that do and the ones that do not fit.
- Think about the biology and try to relate it to the distributions that do and that do not fit.
- look in literature for previous work on this topic.

While Polya in his "how to solve it" might think this is okay, statistics was not his (or my) field.  What feedback would a mature statistician give an aspiring "wanna-be" in this area?

**Updates:**

- My first thought was something like a constant rate **Poisson** point process.  The overall mean is going to be $\mu = \frac{ \left( 11341 - 817 \right) \cdot 1 + \left( 817 \right) \cdot x } { 11341 }$ where x ranges between 7 and 11, which results in a mean between 1.42 and 1.72.  When I repeatedly drew 11,341 samples from a Poisson distribution with means in those ranges, the maximum value was 6, not 15.  From this I infer that the process is not Poisson distributed.
- My second thought was a **Gamma** distribution. The best fit had shape and scale of 0.9947489 and 0.7640226 respectively.  It had 2437 samples with greater than 2 colonies, and 5 samples with greater than 10 colonies.  While it is a less bad fit than the Poisson, it seems to be substantially off.  Instead of populations of 2437 and 5 a good fit would have closer to 817 and 50.
- The **geometric** distribution, like the Poisson distribution, substantially misses the tail, but is close in the mean.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what a "transition of 'physics' in the tail" might mean?

Comment: @whuber - I think there may be growth of the pathogen over time.  It might be slow, or it might be fast, but it may also have a threshold.  If there is some "minimum necessary population" for onset of higher growth, then that would be worth seeing.  I think there may be a biological analog of a "dragon king" hidden in here, but I am terrified to use such vast jargon in CV because such curiosity is sometimes excoriated, and I genuinely want to get to a good answer.

Comment: There are two main categories for distributions, discret event and continius one, poisson is discret and gamma is in another categorie you need to determine what is a nature of your data set.that should.be your first step

Comment: @explorer - When I read (and work through parts of) [this](http://a.co/5Of0gio) I learned that things like galaxies and biological phenomena, though comprised of many distinct, and sometimes weakly interacting "particles" can be described using continuous-valued functions because the mathematics of the function connected with the "physics" of the system being described.  I know that analog to digital converters turn continuous measures into discrete ones, yet engineers treat them as being both continuous, and exact, when they are neither.  Thus I'm afraid to split on discrete/continuous.